# linux arch: systemd-networkd - interfaces not starting after reboot

Tags: arch-linux

I was trying to move to systemd-networkd from netctl without success. When i restart service systemd-networkd i get:

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-03-23 12:42:34 CET; 16min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 1176 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─1176 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Mar 23 12:42:33 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Mar 23 12:42:34 alarm systemd-networkd[1176]: Enumeration completed
Mar 23 12:42:34 alarm systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Mar 23 12:42:34 alarm systemd-networkd[1176]: **eth0: Could not set route: Invalid argument**
```

The file eth0.service under /etc/systemd/network:

```
more /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Address=192.168.1.99/24
DNS=8.8.8.8
[Route]
Gateway=192.168.1.1
```

Moreover after reboot interfaces eth0 and enp1s0 are down but loopback and tun0 are up.

As far as i know gateway is properly set in file eth0.network. What went wrong ? Any ideas what to do and why eth0 is down after reboot ? If you have any ideas please let me know. I have no clue after 3 days reading of internet and looking for solution.

Regards

Bit more informantional output:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep netctl
netctl-auto@.service                       disabled
netctl-ifplugd@.service                    disabled
netctl-sleep.service                       disabled
netctl.service                             enabled
netctl@.service                            static
netctl@enp1s0.service                      static
netctl@my_static_profile.service           static
```

and

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep networkd
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service       disabled
systemd-networkd.service                   enabled
systemd-networkd.socket                    enabled
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in man 5 systemd.network in my fedora laptop I can read this (examples section):

```
Wired adapter using a static IP

/etc/systemd/network/25-wired.network

[Match]
Name=enp1s0

[Network]
Address=10.1.10.9/24
Gateway=10.1.10.1
```

So try setting the gateway directive in the Network section.

Comment: I have switched back meantime to netctl which works fine. Thanks for hint i will try later one more time with your hint.